# В чём отличие инкремента и преинкремента

Tags: c++, c++11

Читал в книге, что при инкрементировании значение возвращает свою копию, лишь затем увеличивается на +1, а при преинкрементировании(поправьте, если неправильно написал) значение не создаёт копию, тем самым возвращает сразу текущее значение увеличенное на +1 и не забивает лишним память. 

Смотрел лекцию, где лектор сказал, что с этими вещами нужно быть аккуратным при точных расчётах, мол, если вам не важна точность, то можете использовать преинкремент (`++i`).

Вбил это себе в голову, теперь хочу спросить у Вас по поводу этого момента.
Например, создадим массив, запишем в него некоторые значения:

```
    int age[4];
    // enter in arr
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
        cout << "Enter age: " << endl;
        cin >> age[j];
    }
    // read
    for (int r = 0; r < 4; ++r)
    {
        cout << "You entered: " << age[r] << endl;
    }
```

Разницы здесь никакой нет (визуально), значения в обоих случаях выводятся корректно.

Comment: *"если вам не важна точность, то можете использовать преинкремент"* - ничего подобного, все пять видов инкремента используют целочисленную арифметику и обеспечивают одинаковую точность.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело здесь не в точности, а в возвращаемом значении.

`i++` **сначала возвращает значение `i`, а потом наращивает его**

`++i` **сначала наращивает значение и потом возвращает уже нарощенное**

Пример:

```cpp
int i = 1;
int j = 1;
cout << ++i; // Выведется 2
cout << i;   // Всё ещё 2, потому что нарастилось сразу
cout << j++; // Выведется 1, потому что сначала возвращает значение, потом наращивается
cout << j;   // Выведется 2, потому что нарастилось после того как возвратило значение в прошлой строке
```

`++i` по объективным причинам работает немного быстрее. Чтобы объяснить это, рассмотрим наивную реализацию обоих операторов:

`++i`:

```cpp
int preincrement(int i) // Вообще операторы определяются не такой синтаксической конструкцией, это для простоты
{
    return i + 1; // Наращиваем и возвращаем нарощенное
}
```

`i++`:

```cpp
int postincrement(int &i)
{
    int result = i; // Сначала сохраняем переданное значение, чтобы потом его вернуть
    i = i + 1; // Наращиваем i
    return result; // Но возвращаем ИЗНАЧАЛЬНОЕ значение
}
/* Больше строк – меньше скорость */
```

Оба оператора абсолютно "точно" инкрементируют значение (не представляю, как можно неточно нарастить число на 1). Гарантировано, что после выполнения обоих операторов с следующей строке значение переменной станет больше на 1.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Лектор чуть сбил с "если вам важна точность значения", возникла путаница и дабы развеять все сомнения решил сюда обратиться, всё же мнение людей с опытом важно услышать.

Comment: @byte_ Всё же я советую обращаться сначала к учебникам. У их авторов, скорее всего, гораздо больше опыта и знаний, чем у участников сообщества.

Comment: На данный момент читаю Р.Лафоре "ООП в С++". Очень все понятно и чётко по делу. Лекции в интернете нахожу, смотрю сейчас лектора Мещерина.
Опыт участников сообщества тоже вещь ценная. Особенно, когда только начинаешь свои первые шаги. Всё же стараюсь по минимуму вопросов задавать, а то еще заминусуют) С чем то сам разбираюсь, но иногда и правда бывают случаи, когда лучше спросить мнение других людей. Спасибо еще раз :)

Comment: Неужели у Лафоре не объяснено различие инкрементов? Тогда, может, Вам стоит начать не с ООП, а с основ языка? Тем не менее, рад помочь :)

Comment: Нет, у Лафоре как раз таки всё понятно, там схемы очень круто придуманы. Меня запутало высказывание лектора по поводу "если вам не важна точность значения". И вот возвращаясь к книге я ничего о подобном не вычитал и был между двух огней. Вы меня возможно не так поняли просто :)
А к книге вообще вопросов нет, прекрасная вещь.

Comment: Важное уточнение - `i++` - rvalue, а `++i` - lvalue (понятно, что для пользовательских типов можно определить как угодно...)

Comment: Единственная разница может быть только для атомарных операций, а там лучше все таки использовать  операцию инкремента явно.